# Get first N items from Iterator

Tags: php, iterator

#### Problem

I have implemented a custom [Iterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) that internally makes HTTP requests to paginated resource (notifications list).

Now I want to use it. I want to get first N items and process (or display) the notifications in batches. I cannot use [iterator_to_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php) as the notifications iterator may be very large or even infinite. In other languages I can use iterator combinators such as: [take](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take), [take_while](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take_while), [takewhile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile), [islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), [Take](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=net-6.0), [TakeWhile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile?view=net-6.0).

The obvious solution I can write is:

```php
$N = 10;
$array = [];
foreach ($iter as $item) {
    if (count($array) >= $N) {
        break;
    }
    $array[] = $item;
}
```

This is quite verbose and produces lot of boilerplate code. The `take_while` operation will look very similar.

#### Question

What is the industry standard way of approaching this problem? Is my modelling of notification stream as `Iterator` incorrect? Should I roll my own "iterator" which will have such methods? What is industry standard method for modelling such concepts in PHP code?

I found the following libraries [nikic/iter](https://packagist.org/packages/nikic/iter), [ihor/nspl](https://packagist.org/packages/ihor/nspl) which seem to contain similar utility methods. But is including a third-party library in my code for consuming Iterators the right-choice?

Answer (score 0):

After digging trough implementations of community libraries I discovered [LimitIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.limititerator.php) <sup>(available from PHP 8.0)</sup> which can be used as `take()`.

```php
$N = 10;
$array = iterator_to_array(new LimitIterator($iter, 0, $N));
```

The Standard PHP Library contains other useful [iterators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php). However there is no way to combine / chain multiple iterators as it is possible in LINQ or in Rust.